# C++ Struct Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, pointers, memory-management

I have a struct defined like this:

```
Struct Example
{
 char arr[MAX_SIZE];
};
```

In a C-style, I can do `Example * pExample = (Example*) malloc(sizeof(Example));` to get a pointer to a dynamically allocated memory. Now I want to know if there's any way I can do the same thing using `auto_ptr` smart pointer, without any change on the data structure.

Thank you

Comment: Are you against the idea of using new and delete operators?

Comment: @BrainSteel: Encouraging someone young and vulnerable to use `new` and `delete` is plain cruel...

Comment: @BrainSteel if possible, I want to aviod changing anything in the data structure... In the above case, `new Example()` won't work, right?

Comment: @KerrekSB He could always use malloc() anyway. And sorry, I've never touched auto_ptr or anything in C++. I'm a C guy, myself.

Comment: @AllanJiang I believe if you use Example* some_ex = new Example(), you'll do effectively the same thing as your malloc().

Comment: What about `std::auto_ptr<Example> pexample ( new Example() );`?

Comment: What do you mean by (not changing the data-structure)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent C++ code would be:

```
Example *pExample = new Example();
```

But if you need a smart pointer I wouldn't recommended `auto_ptr` because it has been deprecated. Rather, use something like `shared_ptr`, or `std::unique_ptr` (C++11):

```
std::shared_ptr<Example> pExample;
```